# Creating a drop down options list using PokeApi

Tags: javascript, frontend, fetch

I am starting to build my first app using the pokeapi.co. I had an idea to do a drop downlist of all 1000~ pokemon and wanted to pull the data from the api. When I request data from "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon" it does give me an array of pokemon names but it is limited to 20. Is there a way I can set the limit to max or all? Also I am not sure if this is the best way to implement the drop down menu so any additional advice or approach is welcome.

Comment: If you look at "Try it now!" part or at the documentation [https://pokeapi.co/docs/v2#resource-listspagination-section](https://pokeapi.co/docs/v2#resource-listspagination-section) , there is the example: "pokemon?limit=100&offset=200" -> [https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=100&offset=200](https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=100&offset=200)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For pokeapi.co, calling any API endpoint without a resource ID or name will return a paginated list of available resources for that API. By default, a list "page" will contain up to 20 resources. If you would like to change this just add a 'limit' query parameter to the GET request, e.g. ?limit=1000. Like this:

```
https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/ability/?limit=1000
```

In my opinion, requesting 1000 items at a time is not an elegant way to do, not to mention the long time the user has to wait for the returned data. Instead, I suggest you to turn it into a table with a search option, split it into pages with a 20-30 items a page, fetching more data as soon as the user moves to a new page